# ¿Se puede usar "sendos" y "ambos" en la misma frase sin sonar reiterativo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Leyendo la noticia [Podemos da por rotas las negociaciones con IU tras la primera reunión oficial](http://www.eldiario.es/politica/Podemos-da-rotas-negociaciones-IU_0_438507187.html) me sonó algo raro la forma en que la entradilla está escrita:

> **Sendas delegaciones de ambos partidos** se han reunido este martes en la
>   sede de Podemos y han constatado sus diferencias insalvables

Es decir, las delegaciones de A y de B se han reunido entre ellas: la delegación de A con la delegación de B.

Me doy cuenta que "sendos" es necesario, porque de lo contrario la frase:

> Las delegaciones de ambos partidos se han reunido...

tendría la interpretación de que cada delegación se ha reunido internamente, no la delegación A con la delegación B.

Sin embargo, la expresión no deja de sonarme forzada. ¿Es correcta? ¿Se podría escribir de alguna otra forma manteniendo el significado?

Como referencia:

> **[sendos, das](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=OABWMMWa5DXX2YWRFFd6)**
>
> (Del lat. singŭlos, acus. de -li).
>
> 1. adj. pl. Uno o una para cada cual de dos o más personas o cosas.
>
> **[ambos](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=jFMWLK71YDXX2yaXxo6T)**
>
> ambos, bas.
>
> (Del lat. ambo).
>
> 1. adj. pl. El uno y el otro; los dos. U. t. c. pron. person. pl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendas es vocabulario formal y poco común. Incluso algunos nativos no conocen bien su significado, por lo que no se nota tanto la reiteración.

No obstante, la frase podría rescribirse:

> Sendas delegaciones de los dos partidos

O bien:

> Las delegaciones de ambos partidos

Pues la frase siguiente elimina toda ambigüedad ("se reunieron en la sede de Podemos...").

Comment: Siendo un poco chisquilloso, "las delegaciones de ambos partidos se reunieron en la sede de Podemos" también podría interpretarse como que cada una se reunió en una sala diferente : )